# Check available processing cores

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ffmpeg

I need to write a transcoding script that issues an appropriate `ffmpeg` command if there are available resources on a Mac machine. The machine is a 2 x 2.66 GHz 6-Core. Basically the logic I want to employ is:

```
[cron every x minutes]
if available_cores:
    pull front file in queue and transcode
else:
    pass
```

How would I check to see if there are available processing units to run `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 3):

Use what Unix gave you :)  I suggest the often-unknown `batch` program (part of `at`) which will invoke the argumented program(s) when the load average falls below a particular threshold, holding them in a queue.  `man batch`

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. Could you please show me a rough code example of how queueing based upon load average would work?

Comment: @David542, as you need to queue a job (a command line, in your case `ffmpeg`), just prepend `batch` to it.  `batch` (or rather `atrun` or `launchd`) will periodically check the load average and if underneath a threshold invoke the queued command, and repeat.  stdout & stderr results are emailed to the Unix user (but generally the job will manage log output).  Configuring the load average threshold is generally Unix-flavor specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the load averages from the uptime command, and if the load is low enough, fire one up. There's not likely to be an idle core because any modern system has enough random low-priority stuff running in the background that you'll just never see one go completely idle for low. So look for a low load average and go based on that.

Answer (score 1):

/proc/cpuinfo will give you a core count

so you could read that and pull a count of cores.

then do a process list and count FFMPEG processes.

subtract one from the other and you are in pretty good shape.

that should give you conditional.

alternatively look at load via uptime and do a conditional based off the value presented.

There is also such a thing as affinity of a process to a CPU in unix under SMP.

Look at the tool taskset.  You might want to setup a process id tracker in /var somewhere and then manage affinity with your script.